# There's a double negative in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar, african-american-vernacular-english

sentence:

> I'm living in los angeles now. I'm clean. legit

> No you ***ain't never*** been clean. dude

is this part → "***ain't never***" is this a case of double negative?

i was in doubt because i see in cambridge that you can't use double negatives i'll post a link to where i see this

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/double-negatives-and-usage

Comment: Well, _ain't_ and _never_ are both negative, so what do you want to call them together? You seem to be expecting them to wipe each other out like antimatter and matter, but [it doesn't work that way](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf). Quite often people use extra negatives -- like the _n-_ in _never_ -- to emphasize the strength of the negation, like saying _It's a long, long, long way_. This is called "Negative Concord" and it's normal in (for example) Spanish and French; in English it's common but stigmatized in many uses.

Comment: i see, i was in doubt because i see in cambridge that you can't use double negatives i'll edit the question and post a link to clarify

Comment: Please edit your post to use correct capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is what is traditionally called a "double negative".

It is a normal construction in many languages, including Old and Middle English, and many varieties of English today, but it fell out of favour in prestige English a couple of centuries ago, and is not part of standard Englishes.

Somewhere along the way, somebody invented a special name for it, along with the nonsensical rationalisation that the negatives "cancelled out"*, presumably to facilitate teaching generation after generation of schoolchildren that the way they spoke their native language was WRONG!

*There *are* contexts in which the negatives can cancel out but they are rare, and strongly marked by emphasis. eg "I've done nothing all day!" "Really, absolutely nothing?" "Well no, I haven't done **nothing**, but I've done very little of importance". But in contexts like the original question, all English speakers will understand what was meant (even those who claim that it means the opposite), and therefore that is what it means.

Comment: Actually this is another case of Latin worship, like "split infinitive", The Roman grammarians said _Simplex negatio negat. Duplex negatio affirmat_ (to which Larry Horn added _Triplex negatio confundit_) And those Latin-worshipping English pedants took it right over for a universal principle, which, being false, caught on immediately and started being part of Proper Grammar, for those who Cared.

Comment: I didn't know that, @JohnLawler. Was that another case of rationalization defying reality, or did Latin really not have intensifying negatives?

Comment: It probly did, but they might not have been considered negatives. The Romans assumed all languages were like theirs. Luckily Greek was enough like Latin to give them a universal feeling; but linguists who didn't distinguish adjectives from nouns, for instance, may not have the best take on real languages.